# Terminal and File Manager Disagree

Tags: gnome-terminal

When I use file manager I see some additional files compared to the files I can access with Terminal even when in super user mode. I have no idea why that is?
[my desktop showing terminal and file manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYHsM.jpg)

Comment: Can you please provide us with screenshots of your file manager and output of the terminal command so that we can help you?  Thanks!

Comment: Most likely you have the 'Show Hidden items' option enabled in the file manager. Use `Ctrl+H` to toggle it. (`Alt+.` in KDE). To view them in the terminal, use `ls --all`

Comment: How do I attach a screenshot in this forum?

Comment: Hopefully the image is now attached to my question

Comment: Just to be sure, what's the output of `mount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your file manager and the terminal are looking at two different directories. There is one `/usr/local` located on the 118GB volume, and another that is located in your root partition. If you click on `Computer` in the file manager, and navigate to `/usr/local`, then you will be looking at the same directory as the terminal. Alternatively, if you navigate to the 118GB volume, and then `/usr/local/` in the terminal, you will be looking at the directory that is shown in the file manager. In Ubuntu, automatically mounted partitions can usually be found in `/media/`.